# XCode Playground: Couldn't Lookup Symbols

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, swift-playground

Co-working with a friend on a SwiftUI Playground and MapKit won't load on my machine, but it does on his.

The error that I receive is:

```
expression failed to parse:
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  nominal type descriptor for _MapKit_SwiftUI._DefaultMapContent
```

The relevant code is:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
import MapKit

struct SearchView: View {
    @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.1195684, longitude: -90.0632266), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
    ...

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion)
                .zIndex(0)
                .onChange(of: mapRegion) { _ in
                    userMovedMap = true
                    print(userMovedMap, showReloadButton, timerAnimation.isActive)
                    timerAnimation.objectWillChange.send()
                }
            ...
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(SearchView()
    .frame(width: SCREEN_SIZE.width, height:SCREEN_SIZE.height))
```

Why won't this playground run on my machine while it does on his? (Using Xcode 13.4.1 and MacOS 12.5)

Answer (score 0):

Playgrounds are very flakey. What I usually do is try to modularise as much as possible with SPM, and run only stuff depending on one or two libraries,

Another piece of advice is to turn off auto-run or,
sometimes juggling the schemes might help, though I'm not sure if this is anecdotal or not.

See more here:
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swift-playgrounds-tips-tricks/